Running a script after a webpack multi-config build
I have a special need for a react project and I can’t find how to do it. My build use webpack and has 3 different configurations (server, css, client), and I need to launch a special script at the end of the webpack build if none of the configuration fails during the build.
The script pack and deploy the app to a backend, and needs to do it even when running the project in dev mode during a watch. Right now I’m using the webpack-shell-plugin-next plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin-next) to trigger special events but the events don’t really fit my needs.
For example, I need an event at the end of a --watch build, there is one : onDoneWatch, but it’s emitted even with build errors. And since the plugin is not added globally but by config I can’t just use the onBuildError event.
Here is a sample of my config file, right now I’m checking the build errors with a variable but I have concurrency problems on subsequent run of watch.
const isWatchMode = process.argv.includes('--watch');
let buildErrors = 0

const clientConfig = {
    name: 'client',
    entry: {...},
    output: {...},
    resolve: {},
    module: {},
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    plugins:
        new WebpackShellPluginNext({
            onBuildError: {
                scripts: [
                    () => buildErrors++
                ],
                blocking: true,
                parallel: false
            }
        })
    ]
};

const cssConfig = {
    name: 'css',
    entry: {...},
    output: {...},
    resolve: {},
    module: {},
    plugins: [
        new WebpackShellPluginNext({
            onBuildError: {
                scripts: [
                    () => buildErrors++
                ],
                blocking: true,
                parallel: false
            }
        })
    ]
};
const serverConfig = {
    name: 'server',
    name: 'css',
    entry: {...},
    output: {...},
    resolve: {},
    module: {},
    plugins: [
        new WebpackShellPluginNext({
            onBuildError: {
                scripts: [
                    () => buildErrors++
                ],
                blocking: true,
                parallel: false
            },
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    mode: 'development'
};

function resetBuildErrors() {
    buildErrors = 0;
}

async function packAndDeploy() {
    console.log("buildErrors before packAndDeploy :", buildErrors)
    
    // If no build errors, pack and deploy the module
    if(buildErrors === 0) {
        resetBuildErrors()

        // We need to return a promise here, otherwise the WebpackShellPluginNext script won't be "blocking"
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const child = spawn(`yarn pack && yarn deploy`, { shell: true });

            // Pipe the console output (stdout) to the current process
            child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

            // Resolve or reject the promise based on the exit code
            child.on('close', (code) => {
                if (code === 0) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    reject(new Error(`Jahia pack & deploy command failed with exit code ${code}`));
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

// Array of configs to build
const configs = [clientConfig, cssConfig, serverConfig];

// In case of watch we add a final config that will do automatic shell commands to trigger the pack and deploy scripts
const sleepTime = 5;
if(isWatchMode) {
    let watchConfig = {
        name: 'watch',
        mode: 'development',
        dependencies: ['client', 'css', 'server'], // Wait for all webpack configs to be done
        entry: {},
        output: {},
        plugins: [
            new ExtraWatchWebpackPlugin({
                // This is an extra list of files to watch for changes,
                files: [
                    'images/**/*',
                    'locales/**/*.json',
                    'resources/**/*.properties',
                    'settings/**/*',
                    'definitions.cnd',
                    'import.xml',
                    'package.json'
                ]
            }),
            new WebpackShellPluginNext({
                onAfterDone: {
                    scripts: [
                        packAndDeploy,
                        process.platform === 'win32' ? 'timeout ' + sleepTime : 'sleep ' + sleepTime,
                    ],
                    blocking: true,
                    parallel: false
                }
            }),
        ]
    };

    configs.push(watchConfig)
}

module.exports = () => {
    return configs
}

Thanks in advance,
